# Flask app ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I am getting the following error:

```
from .util import create_session, conditional_decorator, send_mail_via_gmail
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

when I tried to run my flask app. This is the folder structure of the app.

```
parent-foler/
├── __init__.py
   app/
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── main.py
    ├── tmp
    └── util.py
```

And inside the main module I have this import statement that is causing the error.

```
from .util import create_session, conditional_decorator, send_mail_via_gmail
```

Please note this runs on if I remove the '.' and run it with

```
python3 main.py
```

but will complain if I remove the '.' and run it with

```
gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:5000 uwsgi:app
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar problem once and I solved it by removing the dot `.`

Assuming you have all those listed functions in `util.py`, try importing it like this:

```
from util import create_session, conditional_decorator, send_mail_via_gmail
```

This worked for me.

Comment: yes that works but will error when run using gunicorn

Comment: I am trying to understand why they differences between the 'python3 main.py', and 'gunicorn --bind .... uwsgi:app' commands

Comment: Try removing the `__init__.py` file from the root directory and use `from util import create_session, conditional_decorator, send_mail_via_gmail`. This should work.

Comment: It usually works in production but not development.

Comment: Even with that file if I remove the "." it works when the command is "python3 main.py", but gunicorn needs those "periods" to work ... How can resolve this so it works for any command or I will need to have different versions of the app for production and development